# Visual Studio 2017 ARM cross compiling linker crash

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, arm, cross-compiling

So I have been working on a project for my raspberry pi. But for convenience, I would like to build it using visual studio 2017. It is plugin based so the plugins implement an interface and export a function that returns an instance to the implementing class. The problem I am experiencing is a compiler crash, that only occurs if I try to export said function.

```
extern "C" Plugin __declspec(dllexport) *CreatePlugin(Data *r);
```

This is the declaration for the function the plugin has to implement to return its implementation of the 'Plugin' interface.

The MSVC Compiler gives me the following error message:

```
1>   Bibliothek "build\Debug\Raspberry\libSMH.so" und Objekt "build\Debug\Raspberry\libSMH.exp" werden erstellt.
1>
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
1>
1>  Version 14.15.26726.0
1>
1>  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>  ExceptionAddress         = 0F20CC4E (0F200000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\arm\VCRUNTIME140.dll"
1>  NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000001
1>  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = FEE90000
1>
1>CONTEXT:
1>  Eax    = 00FE5678  Esp    = 006FEE34
1>  Ebx    = 00FE55F8  Ebp    = 006FEE60
1>  Ecx    = 00000080  Esi    = 00FE55F8
1>  Edx    = 00000080  Edi    = FEE90000
1>  Eip    = 0F20CC4E  EFlags = 00010247
1>  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

This does not occur if I remove the __declspec(dllexport) from the function declaration above.

Does anyone have any experience with cross compiling shared libraries for ARM, and might have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

ARM what?

If you’re building for ARM Windows, it worked quite well for Win10 IoT on raspberry pi, and for windows phone. I wasn’t using `__declspec(dllexport)` however, I was using a module definition file to control my exports. The setting is Configuration properties / Linker / Input / Module Definition File. See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-def-files) for more info.

If you’re building for ARM Linux or Android or some other OS, I doubt VC++ compiler supports that target. Use clang instead, it’s an optional component of VS2017.